# Magento 1.9: How to delete a wrong URL pointing to a product review on a different website (same server)?

Tags: magento-1.9, url, product-urls, product-review

I am running two independent websites on a Magento 1.9.3.9 installation. Today I discovered when searching for a product which is sold in one Magento website, that the Google search result returns a URL pointing to the other website on the same server, which is completely wrong and I want to delete it, but how?

To my bad surprise the wrong URL (Google search result) really opens a product review page on Magento:

https://kuul.jp/en/review/product/list/id/3/category/4/

however the product is in another website on the same server:

https://gizzet.com/review/product/list/id/3/category/4/

How is it possible that I can see a product review from a unrelated second website which is for a different company webshop with a completely independent product range. How can I delete that URL? I do not want to show any connection between the two websites. The URL is not listed in URL Rewrite Management. Moreover in the product definition only the "Gizzet" website is selected.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Is this a Multi store setup.

If so check canonical URLs for each of the URL is question.

Comment: Where would I check that? Could you please explain in a bit more detail?

Comment: Multi store: Yes, two websites with each two language store fronts

Comment: Its related to the way you have set your multi store environment.